# Changing image size with the markdown package

Tags: graphics, markdown

I'm using the markdown package to render a markdown file within a latex document:

```
\usepackage{markdown}

\begin{document}
  \markdownInput{test.md}
\end{document}
```

in the markdown file itself, I want to add in an image, like so:

```
![alt text](test.png "My Test Image")
```

This works, but unfortunately, I could not find a way to modify the image size nor alignment via the `markdown` package.

Is there a way of doing so? note that I'd prefer not to have to modify the tex file directly.

Comment: Al least in Rmarkdown works the syntax `![caption](foo.png){widht=80%}` but  working or not in this way,  you should consider the  opposite strategy: use a Rmarkdown document, include some LaTeX if needed and then export to PDF via LaTeX conversion.

Comment: @Fran - That syntax has no effect as part of the markdown package. Your second suggest would defeat my purpose, which is to have people who do not want to learn how to code in LaTeX use markdown which will then be typeset properly.

Comment: RMarkdow is a limited syntax, plain markdown is more limited and makdown inside a LaTeX document as you did is even more limited, and so even simple tasks as centering something is a problem.  Using markdown people do not have to learn LaTeX at all, except when they want things that only LaTeX can do, and then they must switch to LaTeX, yes or yes. That is possible using the markdown package and closing/open  the markdown environment  (not sure if it can this can be used inside the  `\markdownInput`, however)  or writing Rarkdowm and simply insert latex code when needed.

Comment: Let me explain: What is easier for LaTeX and non-LaTeX users?  `*Hello* \fbox{beautiful} *World*` (a complete .Rmd file)  or maybe `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{markdown}
\begin{document}
\markdownBegin 
*Hello* 
\markdownEnd
\fbox{beautiful}
\markdownBegin 
*World* 
\markdownEnd
\end{document}`  (a complete LaTeX document)?  Because in one way or the another, `\fbox{}` must be used if you want the frame in the central word, the real issue is the rest of the document.

Comment: How do I start a bounty on this question?